# Modeling data for soft deletes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement soft delete by having a field on every document `deletedOn` that is either a timestamp or null.  But so far it has caused me some headaches by complicating my queries because I need to filter those documents out in every query.  `deletedOn` is exposed in the UI to delete "permanently" but if the customer reached out to support we could "recover" the data that was "deleted" by just setting the `deletedOn` field back to null.  Is there a better way to model this in a NoSQL db?  I am kind of leaning more towards having separate collections instead?  e.g. `contacts`  `contacts_deleted` and when a `contact` is deleted move it to the other corresponding collection.  But again I am new to NoSQL and so I have no idea if that is going to be better

Comment: Have you tried implement it? What is wrong with your idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up creating two different collections for the non deleted and deleted documents e.g. `contacts` and `contacts_deleted` and then created a firebase function that watches for deletions in the `contacts` collection and copies the document over to the `contacts_deleted` collection.  That way the responsibility of moving the deleted document is not placed on the client.

Comment: You did well, Kdawgwilk.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to store a "status" field with each document. Then you can require this status in your [database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started):

```
match /posts/{post} {
    allow read: if true

    allow create:
        if request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['name','status','created', 'modified'])
}
```

Created and modified are important here only if you want to delete them later, which you set with `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

For example, you could set every document to "published" status, then when you trash it, change it to "trashed". Then you'd query and get only "published" posts this way:

```
db.collection('posts').where('status', '==', 'published');
```

### Optional

Then (optionally) if you wanted to write a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), you could permanently delete all trashed posts older than a specific timestamp if they are older than 30 days.

var now = Date.now();
var cutoff = now - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 30 days
db.collection('posts').where('status', '==', 'trashed').where('modified', '<' cutoff);

Though, pricing-wise, you'd probably be better off just keeping the data as to not incur additional read/write costs since storage is pretty cheap ($0.18/GiB), does not affect performance and reads/writes are relatively expensive.